# If $f \in L^1(M)$, is it true that $f(x) < \infty$ for almost all $x$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $M$ is a measurable space (eg. $M$ is a Riemannian manifold which is compact) and if $f \in L^1(M)$, is it true that $|f(x)| < \infty$ for almost all $x$?

I am trying to figgur out if $u \in H^1((0,T)\times \Omega)$ implies that $u(x,\cdot) \in H^1(0,T)$ for a.a. $x$!!!

Comment: I haven't read carefully, but assume $\mu(f^{-1}(\infty)) > 0$, then $\mu(f^{-1}(\infty)) \cdot \infty \leq \int_M |f| d\mu$... use sequence of increasing simple functions if you prefer.

Comment: Yes, in fact, it's true that $|f(x)|<\infty$ for a.e. $x \in M$. Suppose, to the contrary, that $|f|=\infty$ on a set of positive measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. By definition, a $L^p$ function takes finite values (in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) on a set of full measure (if you are in doubt, check your go-to reference for functional analysis and re read carefully the definition).

Comment: hmm i think your second sentence is a bit confusing??

Comment: I mean read for example the definition on the wikipedia page. You will see that *by definition* of a $L^p$ space, a $L^p$ function cannot take the value infinity on a set of full measure. if wikipedia is not reliable enough for you, take any other reference book, for example Rudin (I don't have it handy, so I cannot copy the definition here).

Comment: so there really is nothing to prove, it's just a question of definition.

Comment: sorry, I meant positive measure and not full measure